# Distinct key with ARRAY_CONCAT with Struct<String, String>

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to do the following with 2 array fields in the table below. The arrays are of type `Struct<String, String>`.

1. Merge the arrays together
2. If there is a duplicate key between the labels.key and project.key, then I only want to keep the kvp from the labels field
3. flatten the combined array into a delimited string an order them (so I can group by)

Example Table Data

```
SELECT 1 as id, ARRAY
  [STRUCT("testlabel2" as key, "thisvalueisbetter" as value), STRUCT("testlabel3", "testvalue3")] as labels, 
  [STRUCT("testlabel2" as key, "testvalue2" as value)] as project
```

The below query does everything except #2 and I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

```
SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT(l.key, ':', l.value) ORDER BY CONCAT(l.key, ':', l.value))
    FROM UNNEST(
    ARRAY_CONCAT(labels, project)) AS l) AS label,
FROM `mytestdata` AS t
GROUP BY id, label
```

Currently this query gives the output:

```
1 testlabel2:testvalue2,testlabel2:thisvalueisbetter,testlabel3:testvalue3
```

But I'm looking for:

```
1 testlabel2:thisvalueisbetter,testlabel3:testvalue3
```

Comment: Are your structs arrays? Can you provide vetter examples of data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry I realize now that my example data is not very clear. I've updated the post to include a query that we create an example of the data. There are 2 arrays (labels and project) and both are of type Struct<String, String>. I'll work at putting it together to make the example data with the query... sorry my knowledge of BigQuery is limited so it might take me a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT key, ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY source LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS value
    FROM ( 
      SELECT 0 AS source, * FROM t.labels UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, * FROM t.project 
    ) 
    GROUP BY key
  ) AS combined_array
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
SELECT ARRAY
  [STRUCT("testlabel2" AS key, "thisvalueisbetter" AS value), STRUCT("testlabel3", "testvalue3")] AS labels, 
  [STRUCT("testlabel2" AS key, "testvalue2" AS value)] AS project
)
SELECT *, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT key, ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY source LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS value
    FROM ( 
      SELECT 0 AS source, * FROM t.labels UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, * FROM t.project 
    ) 
    GROUP BY key
  ) AS combined_array
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result

[image]

Or ... to fully match your expected output - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(x) FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(key, ':', ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY source LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]) x
    FROM ( 
      SELECT 0 AS source, * FROM t.labels UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, * FROM t.project 
    ) 
    GROUP BY key
  )) AS combined_result
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much! I think it'll take me a bit to understand how this is working, but that's what I'm looking for :)